# Trouble getting UIImageView inside ScrollView programmatically

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, constraints

After days of trying, and searching through countless SO/google/YouTube pages, I unclear how to accomplish this: I'm trying to place a single tall, narrow image inside a `UIScrollView` that only takes up a section of the screen, only scrolls vertically, and is preferably only coded programmatically, no Interface Builder at all.

I've managed to create the `scrollView`, set the `backgroundColor` to blue so I can see it and managed to use constraint anchors to pin it exactly where I need it to be. I then added the top and bottom labels as every video tutorial was telling me to, but I've since deleted these as they didn't seem necessary once I added the image.

The problems start as soon as I try to add the image. I've added an example image below as it's a tall, narrow image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRzmh.jpg

If you run the code with the image, you'll see:

1. The image scrolls horizontally as well as vertically. I'd have thought `content.didOffset.x < 0` would work, but apparently not. There's probably a simple method to fix this but I'm yet to find it.
2. If the height of the image is less than the height of the `scrollView`, i want the image to stretch to fit the `scrollView`. I used both `.scaleAspectFit` and `.scaleAspectFill` and neither of these seemed to change anything.
3. The width of the image (or at least, the image I'm using, not the example image) is larger than the section of `scrollView` I have, and it goes off the screen. Again, I'm sure there's an easy fix to this, but I don't know.

Here is my code, but it's probably all wrong.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.frame.size.height = 3000
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return view
    }()

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image:  imageLiteral)
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()

    func setupLayout() {
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        imageView.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height
        imageView.frame.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        setupLayout()
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing the right thing by adding the image as a subview of `scrollView`. I couldn't get the image to scroll at all until I changed it from the subview of view to `scrollView`. The labels in the tutorials I've seen were added that way, and it made more sense to me to add it into the scrollView than the main screen view, but again, this could be wrong.

I'm really not sure if it's the constraints, the `contentSize` or what, but it’s pretty clear I don't know what I’m doing, and I don't want to just wing it, so if anyone knows of any YouTube videos or websites that can help me out, I’d really appreciate it.

Again, apologies. I feel like this is a really simple fix, but I just don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of accomplishing this, but I’d be inclined to set the `zoomScale` of the scroll view appropriate for this image view width, e.g.

```
// we want to make sure we adjust scale as views are laid out

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if imageView.intrinsicContentSize.width != 0 {
        let scale = scrollView.bounds.width / imageView.intrinsicContentSize.width
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scale
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale
        scrollView.zoomScale = scale
    }
}
```

To do that, you’ll have to set the `delegate` of the `UIScrollView`:

```
scrollView.delegate = self    // we need to specify delegate so we can implement `viewForZooming(in:)`
```

And implement `viewForZooming(in:)`:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

---

So pulling that all together:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let sampleImage: UIImage = ...

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // view.frame.size.height = 3000   // not needed as we're using constraints
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .blue
        return scrollView
    }()

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit   // not needed as we're going to let the intrinsic size dictate the size of the image view and therefore no scaling is happening
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    func setupLayout() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.image = sampleImage
        scrollView.delegate = self    // we need to specify delegate so we can implement `viewForZooming(in:)`

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200),
            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 100),
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor),
            imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        // these are not needed because we're using constraints
        //
        // imageView.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height
        // imageView.frame.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupLayout()
    }

    // we want to make sure we adjust scale as views are laid out

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if imageView.intrinsicContentSize.width != 0 {
            let scale = scrollView.bounds.width / imageView.intrinsicContentSize.width
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scale
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale
            scrollView.zoomScale = scale
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: Good trick with the `zoomScale`. That did not cross my mind when thinking about it.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for the answer, this works great!

What would be the best way to change the height of the image if I wanted to? Or would I be better off changing it outside of Swift?

Also one final question if you don't mind - obviously I'd never have got what you have in a million years - where can I learn more about this? Or where can I read how to learn what you've written, so I understand it a lot more?

Thanks again. Have a great day!

Comment: @ProjectDiversion - If it’s a one-off change of image, I’d probably just do it in my image editing tool on my computer. That’s probably easiest. But if you needed to do it programmatically (e.g. multiple dynamic images, contingent on device sizes, etc.), you certainly can, but it’s just more work. It just depends. Re where to learn, I’d don’t have any great suggestions other than search the web for contemporary resources (e.g. Swift 5), as the language has been evolving so quickly and there’s no point in learning older versions.

Comment: The other alternative to making the image taller is to just adjust the `constant` of `topAnchor` and then set the scroll view’s background color appropriately. Dealing with large images is notoriously inefficient.

Comment: Hi Rob. I agree that adjusting the image height outside of Swift is probably the best option. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to constraint the image width to the scrollview width. However you cannot do it directly, because the image is a subview of the scrollview and direct constraint would refer to width of the content of the scrollview not width. I have solved it by adding a layout guide that is constrained to the width of the scrollview "from the outside".

Also when you add constraint for the width you are left with intrinsic constraint for the height and that would change aspect ratio of the image. You need to add a constraint for the original aspect ratio.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "tallimage"))
    let widthGuide = UILayoutGuide()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addLayoutGuide(widthGuide)
    }

    func setupLayout() {
        let ratio: CGFloat = (imageView.image?.size.height ?? 1) / (imageView.image?.size.width ?? 1)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 100),
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor),
            imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),

            // Make the image the same width as the scrollview.
            widthGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthGuide.widthAnchor),

            // Keep the height/width ratio of the image so it is not deformed.
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: ratio),
        ])
    }

}
```

I have also changed style of the code. Feel free to use your original style.

However, I like to

- When I call a method, it is defined below the line where it is used (in order).
- Use `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` when activating more constraints.
- Use simple instance variables (let constants) and configure them later.

Comment: Hi Mirián, thank you for the answer, this works great!

What would be the best way to change the height of the image if I wanted to? Or would I be better off changing it outside of Swift?

Also one final question if you don't mind - obviously I'd never have got what you have in a million years - where can I learn more about this? Or where can I read how to learn what you've written, so I understand it a lot more?

Thanks again. Have a great day!

Comment: It depends what exactly do you mean by changing the height of the image. If you want to stretch it, you can change the constraint for the aspect ratio (changing the multiplier or adding a constant). If you want to crop it, you can add constants to the top and bottom constraints... but it won't be really cropped. Or crop it by wrapping the image view inside another view and set `clipSubviews` to true. Or do some lower-level image transformation on the device. Or modify the image outside of the device.

Comment: I’ll look into the height change and the book. Thanks again!